# SIGSEGV errors that just showed, worked fine before

Tags: list, null, segmentation-fault

I dont have explansion for what happening to my code, i have a generic linked list
and it worked like a charm just yesterday, i didn't change it in any way, but somehow
now when the getters and setters of the list try to reach the fields of the list or it's nodes i getting those SIGSEGV faults and my code terminating, that's the relevant part of my list.c file :

```
struct LinkedList
{
    Node m_head;
    Node m_tail;
    int m_numOfElements;
};


List CreateLinkedList()
{

    List list = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));

    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory alloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    list->m_head = NULL;
    list->m_tail = NULL;
    list->m_numOfElements = 0;

    return list;
}
```

i also have that typedef in the list.h file which included in the ilst.c file:

```
typedef struct LinkedList* List;
```

after debugging for hours i noticed that the head and tail dont get NULL value when the list created, they still have some address instead of zeros, it also happens in the create node and other uses of this list, why is it? my heap is corrupted? why it doesn't assign null to those fields as it should?! anyway plz remember it worked well and i have no idea what changed it.. thanks!

edit:

this is the AddNode function in my node.c file:

```
int AddNode(List list, Element data)
{
    Node newNode;
    //there is no linked list to add the element to
    if(list == NULL)
        return -1;

    newNode = CreateNewNode(data);

    if(newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed allocating memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    //Empty Linked List
    if (list->m_head == NULL)
    {
        list->m_tail = list->m_head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        SetNext(list->m_tail,newNode);
        SetPrev(newNode, list->m_tail);
        list->m_tail = newNode;
    }
    //increase num of elements
    list->m_numOfElements++;
    return 1;
}
```

here on the first call to AddNode, when the list is empty and I'm adding the first element
it jumps the if of empty linked list and go for else that come after that, it shouldn't. what can make this happen in my app code?

edit 2:

ok this is the only struct allocation before i use the list:

```
struct Server_t
{
    List UsersList;
};

Result CreateServer(Server thisServer)
{
    if (thisServer = (Server)malloc(sizeof(struct Server_t)))
    {
        thisServer->UsersList = CreateLinkedList();
        return Success;
    }
    return Failed;
}
```

and the main call it that way:

```
Server mainFacebookServer;
CreateServer(mainFacebookServer);
```

Result is enum, and Server is a pointer to that struct.

edit 3:

```
Node CreateNewNode(Element data)
{
    Node newNode = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct NODE));

    newNode->m_next = NULL;
    newNode->m_prev = NULL;
    newNode->m_data = data;
    return newNode;
}
```

and the setters are:

```
void SetNext(Node node, Node toSet)
{
    node->m_next = toSet;
}
void SetPrev(Node node, Node toSet)
{
    node->m_prev = toSet;
}
```

Comment: As long as you check the return value, you should be OK if you use this code correctly.  The problem isn't here - it is in some of the other code.  You'd better show us enough of the rest of the code to be able to run it.  Are you on Linux?  Do you have [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) available?  If so, use it.

Comment: I'm on VMWare player running ubuntu 11.10 in windows... i dont know what other relevant parts of my code i should put here, the list initialization dont work well..

Comment: You should be able to find `valgrind` for Ubuntu.  Use it.  The code for `CreateNewNode()` is probably relevant; the code for `SetNext()` and `SetPrev()` might be relevant.  Your `CreateServer()` function can't make its mind up between `Server` and `struct Server_t` - is it `typedef Server_t *Server;` that you've not shown?  (Personally, I try to avoid typedefs that hide pointers.)

Comment: i added those functions, i can't expose my structs in the .h files, so how should i use pointers to those structs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code does not do what you think it does:

```
Result CreateServer(Server thisServer)
{
    if (thisServer = (Server)malloc(sizeof(struct Server_t)))
    {
        thisServer->UsersList = CreateLinkedList();
        return Success;
    }
    return Failed;
}
```

If you're going to return the `Server` by value, you must pass a pointer into the function:

```
Result CreateServer(Server *thisServer)
{
    if (*thisServer = (Server)malloc(sizeof(struct Server_t)))
    {
        (*thisServer)->UsersList = CreateLinkedList();
        return Success;
    }
    return Failed;
}
```

The original code both leaks memory and invites segmentation faults because the `struct Server_t` value used after `CreateServer()` returns has not been initialized.

---

#### Working Code

The following code works under `valgrind` (there's system-allocated memory still reachable, but nothing leaked or abused).  The problem was indeed in the `CreateServer()` function, as diagnosed earlier.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef int Element;

typedef struct Node *Node;
struct Node
{
    Node    m_prev;
    Node    m_next;
    Element m_data;
};

struct LinkedList
{
    Node m_head;
    Node m_tail;
    int m_numOfElements;
};

typedef struct LinkedList *List;

struct Server_t
{
    List UsersList;
};
typedef struct Server_t *Server;
typedef enum Result { Failed, Success } Result;

extern Result CreateServer(Server *thisServer);
extern Result AddNode(List list, Element data);
extern void SetPrev(Node node, Node toSet);
extern void SetNext(Node node, Node toSet);
extern Node CreateNewNode(Element data);
extern List CreateLinkedList(void);
extern void DestroyServer(Server server);
extern void DestroyLinkedList(List list);

List CreateLinkedList(void)
{
    List list = (List)malloc(sizeof(struct LinkedList));

    if (list == NULL)
    {
        printf("memory alloc failed\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    list->m_head = NULL;
    list->m_tail = NULL;
    list->m_numOfElements = 0;

    return list;
}

Node CreateNewNode(Element data)
{
    Node newNode = (Node)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));

    newNode->m_next = NULL;
    newNode->m_prev = NULL;
    newNode->m_data = data;
    return newNode;
}

void SetNext(Node node, Node toSet)
{
    node->m_next = toSet;
}

void SetPrev(Node node, Node toSet)
{
    node->m_prev = toSet;
}

Result AddNode(List list, Element data)
{
    Node newNode;
    //there is no linked list to add the element to
    if (list == NULL)
        return Failed;

    newNode = CreateNewNode(data);

    if (newNode == NULL)
    {
        printf("Failed allocating memory\n");
        return Failed;
    }

    //Empty Linked List
    if (list->m_head == NULL)
    {
        list->m_tail = list->m_head = newNode;
    }
    else
    {
        SetNext(list->m_tail,newNode);
        SetPrev(newNode, list->m_tail);
        list->m_tail = newNode;
    }
    //increase num of elements
    list->m_numOfElements++;
    return Success;
}

Result CreateServer(Server *thisServer)
{
    if ((*thisServer = (Server)malloc(sizeof(struct Server_t))) != 0)
    {
        if (((*thisServer)->UsersList = CreateLinkedList()) != 0)
            return Success;
    }
    return Failed;
}

void DestroyLinkedList(List list)
{
    Node node;
    Node next;
    assert(list != 0);
    for (node = list->m_head; node != 0; node = next)
    {
        next = node->m_next;
        free(node);
    }
    free(list);
}

void DestroyServer(Server server)
{
    assert(server != 0);
    assert(server->UsersList != 0);
    DestroyLinkedList(server->UsersList);
    free(server);
}

int main(void)
{
    Server mainFacebookServer;
    if (CreateServer(&mainFacebookServer) == Success)
    {
        if (AddNode(mainFacebookServer->UsersList, 1) == Success)
        {
            /* Use new user list */
        }
        DestroyServer(mainFacebookServer);
    }
    return(0);
}
```

When compiled with the XCode 4.x GCC/LLVM on MacOS X 10.7.2 and run with Valgrind 3.7.0, I get:

```
$ /usr/bin/gcc -O3 -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Werror xxx.c -o xxx 
$ valgrind --leak-check=full xxx 
==51464== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==51464== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==51464== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==51464== Command: xxx
==51464== 
==51464== 
==51464== HEAP SUMMARY:
==51464==     in use at exit: 2,095 bytes in 32 blocks
==51464==   total heap usage: 35 allocs, 3 frees, 2,151 bytes allocated
==51464== 
==51464== LEAK SUMMARY:
==51464==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==51464==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==51464==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==51464==    still reachable: 2,095 bytes in 32 blocks
==51464==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==51464== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==51464== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==51464== 
==51464== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==51464== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 1 from 1)
$
```

When run with `--show-reachable=yes`, the extra reports are similar to this one (from a different run, as you can see:

```
==51375== 616 bytes in 7 blocks are still reachable in loss record 8 of 8
==51375==    at 0xC3F3: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:569)
==51375==    by 0x312AAA: _xpc_calloc (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==51375==    by 0x313384: _xpc_base_create (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==51375==    by 0x319CE2: xpc_string_create (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==51375==    by 0x318EF5: xpc_dictionary_set_string (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==51375==    by 0x31AF49: _libxpc_initializer (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==51375==    by 0x18E7D: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==51375==    by 0x7FFF5FC0FD19: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==51375==    by 0x7FFF5FC0FA65: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==51375==    by 0x7FFF5FC0D257: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==51375==    by 0x7FFF5FC0D1F0: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==51375==    by 0x7FFF5FC0E02A: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==51375==
```

Not exciting - except for the amount of background work going on - and definitely an issue (or not) with the system rather than the code in the program.